# How to validate html using java? getting issues with jsoup library

Tags: java, html, validation, jsoup

I need to validate HTML using java. So I try with jsoup library. But some my test cases failing with it.

For eg this is my html content. I dont have any control on this content. I am getting this from some external source provider.

```
String invalidHtml = "<div id=\"myDivId\" ' class = claasnamee value='undaa' > <<p> p tagil vanne <br> <span> span close cheythillee!!  </p> </div>";

doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(invalidHtml);
```

For above html I am getting this output.

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="myDivId"  '=""  class="claasnamee" value="undaa">
    &lt;
   <p> p tagil vanne <br /> <span> span close cheythillee!! </span></p> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

for a single quote in my above string is comming like this. So how can I fix this issue. Any one can help me please.

Comment: Is JSoup a validating HTML parser?

Comment: yes it is validating and correcting but some cases it is failing

Comment: What do you mean by 'failing' ? The whole purpose of validation is that garbage content will be rejected. So if JSoup can't parse it, you reject it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to validate your html would be http://validator.w3.org/. But that would be manual process. But dont worry jsoup can do this for you as well. The below program is like a workaround but it does the purpose.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class JsoupValidate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String invalidHtml = "<div id=\"myDivId\" ' class = claasnamee value='undaa' > <<p> p tagil vanne <br> <span> span close cheythillee!!  </p> </div>";

        Document initialDoc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(invalidHtml);

        Document validatedDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://validator.w3.org/check")
                .data("fragment", initialDoc.html())
                .data("st", "1")
                .post();

        System.out.println("******");
        System.out.println("Errors");
        System.out.println("******");
        for(Element error : validatedDoc.select("li.msg_err")){
            System.out.println(error.select("em").text() + " : " + error.select("span.msg").text());
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("**************");
        System.out.println("Cleaned output");
        System.out.println("**************");
        Document cleanedOuput = Jsoup.parse(validatedDoc.select("pre.source").text());
        cleanedOuput.select("meta[name=generator]").first().remove();
        cleanedOuput.outputSettings().indentAmount(4);
        cleanedOuput.outputSettings().prettyPrint(true);
        System.out.println(cleanedOuput.html());
    }

}
```

Comment: Er... and if you need HTML validation in a unit test?

Comment: That's not a usage of Jsoup to validate html. That's sending the html to http://validator.w3.org/ and parsing the response

Answer (score 3):

```
var invalidHtml = "<div id=\"myDivId\" ' class = claasnamee value='undaa' > <<p> p tagil vanne <br> <span> span close cheythillee!!  </p> </div>";

var parser = Parser.htmlParser()
        .setTrackErrors(10); // Set the number of errors it can track. 0 by default so it's important to set that
var dom = Jsoup.parse(invalidHtml, "" /* this is the default */, parser);

System.out.println(parser.getErrors()); // Do something with the errors, if any
```